# How to read recent transactions from Uniswap V3 using Python?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to get details on the most recent transactions from the ETH/USDT .3% Uniswap V3 pool.

Using get_price_input() from Uniswap-Python API I am able to read the most recent price for a given pool but the API does not have a function to read Total Value, Token Amount nor whether ETH is being swapped for USDT or USDT for ETH. This link has a good representation of what I'm looking for: https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0x4e68ccd3e89f51c3074ca5072bbac773960dfa36

I am aware that many use The Graph to get hourly or daily data, but that is not fast enough, as I'm looking for the most recent transaction.

Beyond Uniswap-Python API I'm not sure where to start for using python to read recent data directly from the blockchain. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:
I've been reading through the Web3.py and Uniswap documentation.

Here is a way to do it on Uniswap V1 that doesn't work as getEthToTokenInputPrice doesn't work for V3.

```
import json
from web3 import Web3


infura_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXX'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

# uniswap_ETH_USDT.v3
abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"name":"Collect","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"name":"CollectProtocol","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Flash","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNextOld","type":"uint16"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNextNew","type":"uint16"}],"name":"IncreaseObservationCardinalityNext","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"}],"name":"Initialize","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0Old","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1Old","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0New","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1New","type":"uint8"}],"name":"SetFeeProtocol","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0","type":"int256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1","type":"int256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"}],"name":"Swap","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Requested","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Requested","type":"uint128"}],"name":"collect","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Requested","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Requested","type":"uint128"}],"name":"collectProtocol","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"fee","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint24","name":"","type":"uint24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeGrowthGlobal0X128","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeGrowthGlobal1X128","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"flash","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNext","type":"uint16"}],"name":"increaseObservationCardinalityNext","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"}],"name":"initialize","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"liquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxLiquidityPerTick","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"observations","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"blockTimestamp","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulative","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"initialized","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32[]","name":"secondsAgos","type":"uint32[]"}],"name":"observe","outputs":[{"internalType":"int56[]","name":"tickCumulatives","type":"int56[]"},{"internalType":"uint160[]","name":"secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128s","type":"uint160[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"positions","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside0LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside1LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"protocolFees","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"token0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"token1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1","type":"uint8"}],"name":"setFeeProtocol","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"slot0","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationIndex","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinality","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNext","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"unlocked","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"}],"name":"snapshotCumulativesInside","outputs":[{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulativeInside","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsInside","type":"uint32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"zeroForOne","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amountSpecified","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"swap","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int16","name":"","type":"int16"}],"name":"tickBitmap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"tickSpacing","outputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"name":"ticks","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidityGross","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"int128","name":"liquidityNet","type":"int128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthOutside0X128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthOutside1X128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulativeOutside","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityOutsideX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsOutside","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"initialized","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token0","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token1","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]')
address = '0x4e68Ccd3E89f51C3074ca5072bbAC773960dFa36'
exchange_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

# Prices

ETH_AMOUNT = web3.toWei('1', 'Ether')
USDCAmount = exchange_contract.functions.getEthToTokenInputPrice(ETH_AMOUNT).call()
bid_price = web3.toWei(daiAmount, 'Ether')
USDCAmount = exchange_contract.functions.getTokenToEthOutputPrice(ETH_AMOUNT).call()
offer_price = web3.toWei(daiAmount, 'Ether')

print(bid_price, offer_price)
'''
```